# Calculating rotation degrees based on delta x,y movement of touch or mouse

Tags: input, libgdx, rotation

I have an object in 2D space that I want to rotate based on how an input in 2D space moves. Basically, think that you move your finger or mouse around on the screen either clockwise or counter clockwise, and the object rotates relative to how you rotate your finger. The position of the object does not matter at all, meaning the rotation is only translated to the object from the finger movement, and there is no relation between the object's position and the finger movement position.

I am using libGdx and I get the X and Y delta movement (positive and negative integers depending on direction of movement) in a call to a method "touchDragged".

How can I use this delta X and Y to calculate the degrees of movement that I can then apply to my object. Preferably I'd just like to add to a radian or degree value.

I can get it to work fine if only using one axis. I.e. if I move the finger up or down, or rotates either clock-wise or counter-clockwise. My problem is getting it to work as a result of both X and Y movement.

PS: I did a bit of looking around before posting this question and I know there are similar questions but I couldn't figure it out based on them. I don't know exactly why but it seemed like all the different questions were tackling different use cases each one different from mine.

Comment: take a read at [GestureDetector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html) and [GestureListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.GestureListener.html) classes and this [post](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection)

Comment: Yes the GestureListener adds some extra stuff for panning and pinch etc, but it doesn't really help with my problem, as there is no rotation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDIT: as stated by Barodapride, libgdx provide the Vector2 API Vector2.angle(Vector2 Reference) that already returns the float angle value to you, but it's good to know what's going on under the hood]**

Use the cartesian to polar coordinates, your axis position gonna be your 0,0 in your cartesian plane, i can't test it now but you can get the idea by the following code i wrote, take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) for futher reference:

```
public boolean touchDragged(InputEvent event, float posX, float posY, int pointer){
    //Declare and get the position of your axis (in screen coords, you can get that by camera.project()
    Float axisX,axisY;
    axisX = getAxisX();
    axisY = getAxisY();
    //Transform the clicked position to the cartesian plane given the axis
    Float cartesianX,cartesianY;
    cartesianX = posX-axisX;
    cartesianY = posY-axisY;
    //Calculate de radius
    Float radius = Math.sqrt( cartesianX * cartesianX + cartesianY * cartesianY );
    //Get the angle in radians
    Float angleInRadians = Math.acos( cartesianX / radius );
    //Get the angle in degrees
    Float angleInDegrees = angleInRadians *57.2958;
    return true;
}
```

the inverse, to get the x,y from a given radius and angle:

```
double x = getAxisX() + Math.cos( angleInRadians ) * radius;
double y = getAxisY() + Math.sin( angleInRadians ) * radius;
```

Comment: What is getAxis() doing here and and why do I need it? Also I'd like to point out that the touchDragged doesn't provide a position, but a delta of movement since the last touchDragged was called. It seems you are using the position rather than the delta.

Or perhaps it isn't possible to only use the delta to do this, and the starting position of the onTouchDown event must be used?

Comment: its the position of your object projected to your screen, to calculate the angle between those 2 vectors you need to work with 'em positions at the same plane, just use the Vector API as stated by Barodapride

Comment: I just noticed I was wrong in saying it doesn't provide the position, just wanted to point that out.

Comment: reading again your question, you need to inform the object position of your game world to the method, you can't relate the Δx and Δy (linear velocity) to a angle based on a position on screen, it's impossible to get an angle from an linear velocity without the position. Your screencords differs from your gameworld coords, so you must convert your gameworld coords to screencoords via camera.project(obj.getPosition) and do the math to find the angle related between them, after that you must calculate your angular velocity. If you don't want to do the math for yourself just use Box2D.

Comment: I really recommend you to use [box2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) with [steering behaviours](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/Steering-Behaviors) if you don't want to handle the math by yourself, don't know why you would do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Make a Vector2 from the difference in X and Y. Use Vector2.angle() to get the angle of the vector relative to the x-axis. Apply that angle to your sprite object.

[Vector2 API](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of retrieving angle from [x0, y0] to [x1, y1] is using `Math.atan2(y, x);` (which finds the angle difference from the x axis).

Essentially, you could do something like this;

```
//direction from old to new location in radians, easy to convert to degrees
dir = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

(I've got a cold, not thinking straight today, this might give the exact opposite direction, in which case just add PI or 180° or w/e to flip it).